# my base_path is empty do I need to set this manually or is something else wrong?

Tags: 7, uri

I've tried putting in these values in my return:

```
base_path();

global $base_path;
$base_path;

$GLOBALS['base_path'];
```

They all end up returning nothing, while an appended string shows up just fine:

```
return '<div>' . base_path() . drupal_get_path('module','bannert') . "banner.html" . '</div>';
```

Comment: `global $theme_path, $base_url` is available.

Comment: @Clive Yes, My comment shows that !

Comment: What does the last code show?

Comment: The last bit of code shows the end of a function which returns a simple div just to debug why base_path is empty. This function is called by a hook_block_view in it content to be precise.

Comment: but I think its better to use url(drupal_get_path('module','bannert') . "/banner.html")

Comment: I meant, what is the output of that code?

Comment: @kiamlaluno a div with the url inside... is that what you mean?

Comment: The question is, what path do you see? Do you see "/sites/all/modules/bannert/banner.html"? Do you see anything else?

Comment: yeah that's what i see well not exactly because I've put it in modules/custom so it shows up as: `/sites/all/modules/custom/bannert/banner.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't printed/returned any of your examples. It should be

```
print base_path();

global $base_path;
print $base_path;

print $GLOBALS['base_path'];
```

or

```
return base_path();

global $base_path;
return $base_path;

return $GLOBALS['base_path'];
```

Depending on the context.

A line with just a variable on it is valid PHP, but it won't do anything with the variable unless you tell it to.

**EDIT**

It's also worth considering what exactly you're expecting `base_path()` or `$base_path` to contain. The docs say this:

> Returns the base URL path (i.e., directory) of the Drupal installation.
>
> base_path() adds a "/" to the beginning and end of the returned path if the path is not empty. At the very least, this will return "/".

Unless you have your Drupal installation in a sub-folder of the web root (e.g. http://localhost/drupal/), this function/variable will always give you the value '/'.

Comment: maybe my question was unclear but I've placed the `$base_path` `base_path()` `$GLOBALS['base_path']` in my return ( which is the second code part of my question )

Comment: I'd try to print directly in the function anyway, at least to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What are you expecting `base_path()` to contain? For the majority of sites it will just be '/'. Quote from the docs page: 'At the very least, this will return "/".'

Comment: @Clive well that makes things clear, turns out base_path was just "/" and I was expecting it to be at least a one word string. If you'll post that in your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @FLY Will do :)